# Using Symfony2 with HTTPS on localhost

Tags: ssl, https, symfony-2.3

I'm stuck with this issue for quite a while now. I checked this page and Google, but couldn't find anything. Maybe I'm just looking for the wrong key words.

I installed a self signed SSL Certificate into my localhost. That works fine, my browser (after import) recognizes this as a legal certificate and shows the green lock and the green "https". But here is my problem:

I'm developing a application with Symfony2 (2.3.3) and everything works fine. But of course, I want to use https now. As soon as I access a page via https, it gives me the 404 Not Found error page. When I access the same page via http, it works just fine.

I read about the [scheme attribut](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html) for the routes, but I think this is not the problem, because it does not work with this either. Same with the requires_channel attribut in the access_control.

Apparently I am missing something. What is that?

Answer (score 1):

the [Symfony2 Community on Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/109013871316146116610) helped me out. I just forgot to configure the SSL certificate in my vHost configuration. Should look something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile PATH/TO/file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile PATH/TO/file.key

ServerName domain.name
ServerAlias *.domain.name
```

Thank you anyway for your attention.